# How to retrieve a unique identifier number process (Like PID) for a unique nodejs AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a AWS-lambda function running in NodeJs.
I want to identify the process with is running this lambda, something that must be unique like a PID.

Let's imagine that the same lambda has 1000 concurrent brothers running in parallel (same time). Even like that I would like to identify each lambda process uniquely.

For that propose I am using `context.awsRequestId` with gives-me something like - `dbd73414-1da5-477a-96a3-496ff3b23596`.

Is this the correct approach? Can I accept this id to be unique between all instances for the same lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.awsRequestId` gives you a unique identifier for each invocation request so the concurrent invocations should have different request id. If you would like to differentiate each process instead of each invocation, you may want to use a unique id generator in your function like `uuidv4` and create the id outside of the handler.

```js
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const pid = uuidv4();
```

Comment: `identifier for each invocation` This is what I want. By the way, if I use `uuidv4()` it should endUp to the same correct? The `context.awsRequestId` and `uuidv4` will crete a unique flag. is it correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both unique. I suggested creating a unique id outside the handler for the case that you would like to have the same id for requests to the same instance (lambda is warm) but different for other concurrent executions, but since you need an identifier for each invocation, `context.awsRequestId` should suffice.